# NServiceBus second level retries using transactional messages without Raven or Database dependency

Tags: nservicebus

Is there any way to configure second level retries without taking an additional dependency on RavenDB or making database schema changes?

We have an existing system that uses NServiceBus with transactional message queues and are self-hosting NServiceBus in a .NET Windows service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second level retries makes use of the timeout management capabilities in NServiceBus, which you can configured to use NHibernate rather than RavenDB as described at the bottom of this page: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/nhibernate/

Comment: Thanks Udi. The reason for asking is because there's nothing about a new Raven/RDBMS requirement on the 'Second Level Retries' page on the NServiceBus website. The automatic creation of 'timeouts' and 'retries' queues when the feature is enabled added to the confusion.